# Scratch org feature "WorkThanksPref" raises error "An unknown server error occurred"

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

Adding the "WorkThanksPref" to a scratch org definition file is preventing a scratch org from coming up. The error is:

> An unknown server error occurred. Please try again. If you still see this error, contact Salesforce support for assistance. Include the information from "sfdx force:data:record:get -s ScratchOrgInfo ...

If it matters, here's the whole file:

```
{
    "orgName": "Scratch Test",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": [
        "AnalyticsAdminPerms",
        "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
        "FieldAuditTrail",
        "HealthCloudUser",
        "PersonAccounts",
        "PlatformConnect",
        "ProcessBuilder",
        "ServiceCloud",
        "Workflow",
        "WorkThanksPref"
    ]
}
```

Comment: We've been receiving HUGE numbers of these errors generating scratch orgs over the past few days/weeks. Usually within our CI process. Some scratch creations work, some fail, try and retry again. Eventually, it will be successful. This isn't a case of hitting the active scratch org limit, there's something else going on with the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As the comment on the question points out, this may also be due to flakiness of Salesforce scratch org creation rather than a configuration issue. I received three errors in a row trying to deploy the scratch org def in question and the error went away after removing extra scratch orgs, but that may have just been a coincidence.

Orinal answer:

Sigh... I think this is yet another pitfall of Salesforce having poor error messages.

After logging in to my production instance and going to App Launcher > Active Scratch Orgs, I found there were 28 active scratch orgs. This is far less than the limit Salesforce claims to have, but after deleting a bunch of these, my scratch org is now initializing.

Developing with scratch orgs on Salesforce is a painful experience. There are so many pitfalls.